# Can we create page template or modulize UI page using handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

Can I use `handlebars` to create template or module structure like this

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    //include module A src
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    //include module B src
  </div>
</div>
```

If it cannot, what is a good template engine that can couple with nodejs do achieve the above? I come from java web framework, and this can be achieve very easy but it is not so apparent here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [partial section](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/#partials) of handlebarsjs docs.

So first you register the partials:

```
Handlebars.registerPartial('moduleA', fs.readFileSync('moduleA.html'));
Handlebars.registerPartial('moduleB', fs.readFileSync('moduleB.html'));
```

Then in the html you do this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    {{> moduleA}}
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    {{> moduleB}}
  </div>
</div>
```